# We need to show ${a_n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $ 0<\alpha <1$ then we need to show that the sequence ${a_n}$ converges where

$$a_n = -\frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{1- \alpha} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}$$

I tried but all I could do was show $a_{n+1}< a_n$.

Comment: Looks like a job for the Euler–Maclaurin summation formula, or at least an elementary derivation of the first couple of terms thereof.

Comment: @Chappers EMF is way overkill, trapezoidal rule with bounds should suffice.

Comment: Or, indeed, the full form of the integral test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac {dt}{t^\alpha}\le \frac {1}{k^\alpha}\le \int_{k-1}^k\frac {dt}{t^\alpha}$$

Comment: I get $$ \frac{(n+1)^{1- \alpha} - n^{1- \alpha} -1 }{1- \alpha} \leq a_n \leq 0$$. then?

Comment: @manhattan then use $(n+1)^{1-a} \geqslant n^{1-a}$

Comment: Thanks.... using this we get that $a_n$ is bounded for all n and hence by monotone convergence we get the convergence.